Flutter Build Error: Multiple build operations failed due to conflicting plugin paths
`I'm encountering a build error in my Flutter project with the message "Multiple build operations failed." The error log indicates that several plugins, including google_sign_in_android, are failing to generate unit test configurations.
enter image description here``enter image description here
I'm trying to build my Flutter app for Android, but I'm encountering a build error with the message "Multiple build operations failed`

have you tried flutter clean and flutter pub get
